# GameCenter - One leaderboard for each level

Tags: ios, game-center

In a game that contains dozens of levels (more that a hundred), I wish to display/store the highest scores for each level.

I saw in the [API documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH6-SW13) that a maximum of 25 leaderboard categories can be created...

Is there any way to achieve this per-level high scores management? With one single leaderboard with a special parameter indicating the level number? Or is there a way to generate automatically all the level leaderboards?

Comment: This question might be better suited to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: yep, actually I wasn't really sure where to post it... I'll try gamedev then. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Game Center leaderboard system is obviously not suited for this approach (one leaderboard per level).

I think the idea is to store global scores and have one leaderboard per difficulty level for instance.

I'll probably have to redesign my scoring system to fit the Game Center approach.

Comment: Starting with iOS7, `Leaderboard sets` allow upto 500 leaderboards!

Answer (score 2):

Look at the context property of GKScore - which is a 64-bit unsigned integer - that way you may be able to assign different values for the context for different levels and filter that data when you get the scores from leader boards (this will probably require you to use your own UI to display high scores rather than the generic GKLeaderboardViewController) - good luck and let me know how it goes.

Comment: That sounds a good idea. My only concern is that I'm gonna mix in the same leaderboard scores that are not comparable (expected scores are tightly linked to the level length, difficulty,...). And even if I always use level-filtering when accessing the LB from my app, it is still browsable in the Game Center app (which does not really makes sense)

Answer (score 0):

You can't create more than 25 leaderboards. But you can use another solutions to do this.

Comment: You can use: 1 OpenFeint (but if you create more than 50 leaderboards you must write you own UI); 2 Crystal; 3 Plus+;